# Creación de módulo para la lectura de un archivo (texto plano)

Tags: python

Realizar un módulo que contenga una función que reciba como parámetros:
archivo (nombre del archivo o ruta del archivo mas nombre, como se vio en clases)
separador (caracter de separación del archivo)
Ejemplo de llamado a la función:

```
print(leer_archivo("nombre_archivo.csv", ";"))
```

Como resultado se deberá imprimir una lista que contenga tuplas, ese es el formato que se necesita para guardar varias líneas en un archivo con la clase csv (como lo vimos en clases), cada tupla representa una fila y cada elemento de la tupla representa un columna en esa fina.

Ejemplo de lo que debe devolver la función:

```
[('Empresa', 'Año', 'Monto Ventas', 'Mercado',
'Cantidad'), ('Chevrolet', '2010', '105', '20', '95'),
('Targit', '2010', '68', '114', '46')]
```

Nota:  Los errores deben ser controlados, si la función tiene algún error en el proceso, se deberá captura y presentar en pantalla.

ahora yo hice esto de aqui y no se si esta bien:

```
import csv

csv_filepathname1 = "Base_autos.csv"

dataReader = csv.reader(open(csv_filepathname1,"r"),delimiter=";")

lista = []

for row in dataReader:
     temporal = tuple(row)
     print(temporal)
```

Quisiera saber otra opinion y gracias
Esto es parte del archivo csv

```
Mitsubishi;2010;100;20;3        
Honda;2010;100;20;3     
UB Trucks;2010;103;214;111  
Toyota;2010;128;287;159     
Mercedes;2010;81;136;55     
Chery;2010;73;125;52        
Nissan;2010;100;20;3        
Jmc;2010;5;9;4      
Chevrolet;2011;111;208;97       
Targit;2011;89;148;59       
Ufan;2011;112;182;7     
Volkswagen;2011;121;232;111 
Renault;2011;105;249;144        
Chevrolet;2011;78;126;48        
Hynduai;2011;117;232;115        
Porsche;2011;100;20;3       
Skoda;2011;100;20;3     
Hino;2011;45;86;41      
Mazda;2011;142;27;128       
Citroen;2011;135;264;129        
Kia;2011;151;28;129     
Mitsubishi;2011;98;155;57       
Honda;2011;54;108;54        
UB Trucks;2011;127;229;102  
Toyota;2011;129;289;16      
DongFeng;2011;65;111;46     
Mercedes;2011;92;179;87     
BMW;2011;73;119;46      
Chery;2011;7;119;49     
Nissan;2011;100;20;3        
Jmc;2011;59;10;41       
Chevrolet;2012;138;234;96       
Targit;2012;4;91;51     
Ufan;2012;145;226;81        
Volkswagen;2012;115;225;11  
Renault;2012;104;246;142        
Chevrolet;2012;66;107;41        
Hynduai;2012;13;238;108     
Porsche;2012;71;91;2        
Skoda;2012;26;82;56     
Hino;2012;76;136;6      
Mazda;2012;149;27;121       
Citroen;2012;146;271;125        
Kia;2012;134;262;128        
Mitsubishi;2012;95;156;61       
Honda;2012;2;85;65      
UB Trucks;2012;132;234;102  
Toyota;2012;125;295;17      
Mercedes;2012;61;136;75     
Chery;2012;49;105;56        
Nissan;2012;35;84;49        
Jmc;2012;8;127;47       
Chevrolet;2013;100;20;3     
Chevrolet;2013;133;247;114  
Targit;2013;47;89;42        
Ufan;2013;153;256;103       
Volkswagen;2013;141;274;133 
Renault;2013;102;257;155        
Chevrolet;2013;74;131;57        
Hynduai;2013;151;266;115        
Porsche;2013;100;20;3       
Porsche;2013;96;146;5       
Skoda;2013;61;115;54        
Hino;2013;79;168;89     
Mazda;2013;147;271;124      
Citroen;2013;135;257;122        
Kia;2013;16;293;133     
Mitsubishi;2013;119;187;68  
Honda;2013;66;115;49        
UB Trucks;2013;132;234;102  
Great Wall;2013;100;20;3        
Toyota;2013;145;315;17      
Ford;2013;45;107;62     
DongFeng;2013;100;20;3      
Mercedes;2013;8;135;55      
BMW;2013;91;136;45      
Lifan;2013;115;191;76       
Chery;2013;4;88;48      
Nissan;2013;7;166;96        
Jmc;2013;82;161;79      
Chevrolet;2014;82;133;51        
Chevrolet;2014;116;238;122  
Targit;2014;59;109;5        
Ufan;2014;153;276;123       
Volkswagen;2014;119;257;138 
Renault;2014;118;241;123        
Chevrolet;2014;78;124;46        
Hynduai;2014;14;263;123     
Porsche;2014;42;6;18        
Porsche;2014;98;178;8       
Skoda;2014;92;188;96        
Hino;2014;87;19;103     
Mazda;2014;109;23;121       
Citroen;2014;106;223;117        
Kia;2014;136;261;125        
Mitsubishi;2014;11;161;51       
Honda;2014;96;174;78        
UB Trucks;2014;107;21;103       
Great Wall;2014;32;67;35        
Toyota;2014;119;259;14      
Ford;2014;98;183;85     
DongFeng;2014;100;20;3      
Mercedes;2014;88;151;63     
BMW;2014;91;147;56      
Lifan;2014;12;218;98        
Chery;2014;5;99;49      
Nissan;2014;98;216;118      
Jmc;2014;69;118;49      
Chevrolet;2015;77;145;68        
Chevrolet;2015;95;205;11        
Targit;2015;8;143;63        
Ufan;2015;146;257;111       
Volkswagen;2015;108;253;145 
Renault;2015;104;246;142        
Chevrolet;2015;58;118;6     
Hynduai;2015;121;228;107        
Porsche;2015;87;15;63       
Porsche;2015;92;182;9       
Skoda;2015;78;176;98        
Hino;2015;78;182;104        
Mazda;2015;102;214;112      
Citroen;2015;105;217;112        
Kia;2015;112;219;107        
Mitsubishi;2015;108;205;97  
Honda;2015;100;20;3     
UB Trucks;2015;104;21;106       
Great Wall;2015;100;20;3        
Toyota;2015;105;244;139     
Ford;2015;91;171;8      
Jacr;2015;74;165;91     
DongFeng;2015;100;20;3      
Mercedes;2015;74;127;53     
BMW;2015;100;20;3       
Lifan;2015;117;213;96       
Chery;2015;100;20;3     
Nissan;2015;86;193;107      
Jmc;2015;44;112;68      
Chevrolet;2016;32;94;62     
Chevrolet;2016;43;147;104       
Targit;2016;100;20;3        
Ufan;2016;118;247;129       
Chevrolet;2016;5;123;73     
Volkswagen;2016;95;219;124  
Renault;2016;86;211;125     
Chevrolet;2016;100;20;3     
Volvo;2016;55;119;64        
Hynduai;2016;112;25;138     
Porsche;2016;47;102;55      
Porsche;2016;100;20;3       
Porsche;2016;22;108;86      
Skoda;2016;5;156;106        
Hino;2016;100;20;3      
Mazda;2016;100;20;3     
Citroen;2016;77;194;117     
Kia;2016;109;271;162        
Mitsubishi;2016;54;1104;105 
Honda;2016;100;20;3     
UB Trucks;2016;5;125;75     
Great Wall;2016;100;20;3        
Toyota;2016;57;193;136      
Ford;2016;72;149;77     
QRC;2016;75;153;78      
Jacr;2016;12;92;8       
DongFeng;2016;100;20;3      
Zotye;2016;52;153;101       
Mercedes;2016;53;131;78     
BMW;2016;100;20;3       
Lifan;2016;95;188;93        
Jac;2016;31;15;119      
Chery;2016;100;20;3     
Nissan;2016;97;226;129      
Jmc;2016;100;20;3
```

Segun yo copie el codigo como mandaste ahi, cambie el nombre donde estaba guardado en la lista a archivo, despues de eso mande a imprimir y en la consola sale vacio

```
    import csv
    def abrir(archivo):
        with open(archivo) as f:
            lineas = [tuple(l.rstrip().split(";")) for l in f.readlines() if l.rstrip()]
        print(lineas)
```

Comment: Podrías hacer una lectura por líneas con la función `open` nativa de python

Comment: lo que pasa estimado que el profesor quiere una función, osea que eso llame una función y le imprima el resultado en tuplas, yo honestamente no entiendo que mismo hace, por eso puse de esa manera pero si hay otra seria bueno saberla

Comment: Empresa;Año;Monto Ventas;Mercado;Cantidad
Chevrolet;2010;105;20;95
Targit;2010;68;114;46
Ufan;2010;101;156;55
Volkswagen;2010;12;25;13
Renault;2010;11;253;143
Chevrolet;2010;100;20;3
Hynduai;2010;12;217;97
Porsche;2010;100;20;3
Skoda;2010;100;20;3
Hino;2010;65;116;51
Mazda;2010;149;274;125
Citroen;2010;112;24;128
Kia;2010;148;26;112
Mitsubishi;2010;100;20;3
Honda;2010;100;20;3
UB Trucks;2010;103;214;111
Toyota;2010;128;287;159
Mercedes;2010;81;136;5

Comment: eso es lo que hay en el csv

Comment: debes de hacer el llamado a la funcion `abrir("archivo.csv")`

Comment: puse archivo=open("./archivo.csv","r") y de ahi el resto del codigo que me mandaste y nada

Comment: nop eso no sirve, haz lo que te digo

Comment: digame como le hago, paso a paso o linea por linea, porque como le dije solo copie el codigo como tal y en la consola no imprime nada

Comment: edite mi respuesta, avisame si lo logras

Comment: ahora si salio por fin!!!! Gracias mi estimado pero ahora una ultima consulta, como puedo hacer que la lista vaya para abajo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo puedes hacer de forma sencillamente una comprensión de lista, donde leeremos todo el archivo con el método `readlines()` lo que nos devuelve una lista con cada línea, luego usamos el método `split()` para separar la cadena porosas comas, finalmente convertimos a tupla

```
def abrir(archivo):
    with open(archivo) as f:
        lineas = [tuple(l.rstrip().split(";")) for l in f.readlines() if l.rstrip()]
    print(lineas)

#llamamos a la funcio
abrir("archivo.csv") #pones el nombre tu archivo
```

Esto imprimirá una lista con cada valor como tupla. SI quieres imprimir linea por linea, solo tendríamos que recorrer la lista otra vez, pero por que recorrer la lista otra vez?, mejor simplificamos todo en un solo `for`.

```py
def abrir(archivo):
    with open(archivo) as f:
        for linea in f.readlines():
            print(tuple(linea.rstrip().split(";")))
```

Solo como breve explicación, `rstrip()` se utiliza para quitar espacio y saltos de linea de una cadena, `split()` separa una cadena según el caracter que le especifiquemos, y `tuple()` convierte un dato a tupla.

Comment: osea con eso ya copio y meto el código y arranca de una?

Comment: pues sip, solo le pasas como parámetro el nombre del archivo algo así `abrir("archivo.csv")`. En cuanto a los errores deberás usar un `try/except`

Comment: cuando mande a la consola a imprimir no me sale nada, solo vacío... disculpa por ser insistente pero realmente quiero aprender :(

Comment: no te preocupes para eso esta esta comunidad, para aprender. podrías editar tu pregunta añadiendo como es que tienes tu código ahora?

Comment: listo estimado ahi lo puse

Comment: ahora si salio por fin!!!! Gracias mi estimado pero ahora una ultima consulta, como puedo hacer que la lista vaya para abajo?

Comment: Ietras en la lista y haces un print

Comment: Lo puedes hacer como tu `for row ...` pero lo haces en la variable lista, obviamente dentro de la función `abrir`, si quieres que lo agregue avísame

Comment: si no es mucha molestia mi estimado, estaría muy agradecido

Comment: OK, lo hago mañana, por acá yanes algo tarde

Comment: no hay problema mi estimado, realmente aprecio que haya personas en este mundo como usted, mil gracias por todo :)

Comment: ya hice la edición, lo siento por demorarme